# delete service by "system" user failed

Tags: windows, windows-7, service

I'm runnig a software to be tested. the software is running by `SYSTEM` user, and can apply actions on the machine. The software has a service that runs. 
In one Win7 machine, when the `SYSTEM` user is trying to delete the service (as part of auto update to the software) it seem to be failed . The service is stopped, with a message:

> The service has been marked for deletion.

Only reset can solve that issue, but we need a better solution to forcly delete that service, so the process of auto-update will be as much as reliable. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an older KB article which might help:

> To work around this problem, restart the computer before you reinstall
>   the service.
>
> Note If you first verify that the service is stopped, and then you
>   quit the Microsoft Management Console (MMC) before you remove the
>   service, you may be able to reinstall the service without restarting
>   the computer.

[BUG: "The specified service has been marked for deletion" error message when you reinstall a service in Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823942/en-us)

Additionally, why to you delete the service, and not just stop it, update the binaries, and start the service again? No need for uninstall... ?